# How can I set an icon for a quickly application?

Tags: python, ubuntu, glade, canonical-quickly

How can I set an applications image (icon) in my canonical-quickly project? Even if I set the icon path in Glade, the UI designer, my icon doesn't show up.

In the aplications bar of my desktop I only see a gear.

I used the following relative path in Glade:

```
../media/projectname.svg
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while but anyway...
You should put it here:

```
YOUR_QUICKLY_PROJECT_FOLDER/data/media/YOU_PROJECT_NAME.svg
```

(.png/.jpg might work also, I am not sure)

And you don't need to set it anywhere in the programme.